# How wifi/bluetooth speaker can get audio data?

Tags: wifi, audio, bluetooth, speakers

As I said in title? How a wifi/bluetooth speaker can get audio data from your device such as phone or PC?
I have an bluetooth speaker and any sound from my phone is sent to that speaker - How they can do that.
Even with wifispeaker, I see that some must run with a program, but some doesn't. Just turn on speaker, connect to your device and you can stream any sound to it.

Thank you

Comment: For Bluetooth it's A2DP, a standard protocol used by most devices, it's not Apple-specific and is compatible with a wide range of devices. For Wi-Fi (or Ethernet, as it only requires an IP connection, the physical link doesn't matter) it's Airplay, an Apple-specific technology that uses Bonjour (Zeroconf) for device discovery, and RTSP for the audio data itself. More info : http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/AirPlay and http://git.zx2c4.com/Airtunes2/about/

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/A2DP.aspx) on the Bluetooth specification website very quickly descends into technobabble, but the Advanced Audio Distribution Profile is how audio is distributed, or sent, from a Bluetooth audio transmitter (such as iPhone or iPod) to a Bluetooth audio receiver (such as headphones or a stand-alone speaker).

I am not sure how technical of an answer you are looking for, but the page linked above goes into much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

On re-reading, this may not be the actual answer… if it's bluetooth, then it's bluetooth - but if it works in Airplane mode, then read on...

Simply put, they work by **induction**.
They actually 'listen' to the magnetic field in the phone's speaker itself.

If you pass an alternating current through a wire wrapped round a magnet, the current will induce a magnetic field, causing the magnet to move.
If you attach that magnet to a paper or plastic cone - you have a speaker.

Conversely, if you vibrate that cone, you induce a current in the wire coil - & there you have a microphone.

The magnetic field generated by the speaker coil is very low, but is just strong enough that if you put a 'receiver' consisting of another coil & magnet, you can generate just enough current to power a small amplifier, which can then re-transmit that to a new speaker as amplified sound.

[There must be some kind of shielding or suppression circuit in there to prevent it 'hearing' itself, but that's above my expertise-level]

You can test this theory very simply…
Put your iPhone in Airplane mode & test it on the speaker.
The phone is not transmitting anything by radio, so it must be induction.

Comment: While this is possible in theory, do you actually know any speakers that use this technology ? I really don't see the point of it, as using Bluetooth or just a plain old Lightning connector is way easier and provides better quality.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Yes - I tested it with my own [rather cheap] induction speakers. (I'm also an audio engineer, so I over-simplified the structure, but the theory is sound [pardon the pun] nonetheless) Induction is a system that will work with any device with a speaker in it - far less hi-tech than bluetooth/wifi, but fine for low-rez repro of an iPod if you're on holiday in Greece etc. I wouldn't use it to check my latest mix ;)

Comment: But this requires the phone to be extremely close to the induction receiver coil, right ? In this case, again, using the Lightning connector or the audio jack seems easier and more reliable, so I doubt a commercial product would use that induction technology.

Comment: On it, yes. It's still a valid method - lot cheaper than providing interface to all the current phone connectors/protocols. [I'm not claiming it's good, merely that it exists]